# Identification of vector valued function

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Do you know of a good reference for a proof of the fact that $L^2(0,T,L^2(\Omega))$ and to $L^2([0,T]\times \Omega)$ can be identified?

Comment: Have a look at Proposition 1.2.24 in T. Hytonen, J. Van Neerven, M. Veraar and L. Weis, Analyis in Banach spaces Vol I, Springer,

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Can you please post your comment as an answer? I will then accept it, and mark my question as concluded.